# how to set redirect using WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

in the controller, I save the object. the saveOrUpdateUser method returns mono. but the redirect is faster than the object is saved to the database. Since I do not get this object in another method where the redirect occurs.

```
@PostMapping("users/{id}")
    public String saveOrUpdateUser(User user, Model model) {
        Mono<User> userDb;
        if (user.getId() == null) {
            userDb = userService.registerUser(user);
        } else {
            userDb = userService.update(user);
        }
      
        userDb.subscribe();
 
   
            return "redirect:/admin/users";
    }
```

redirect to:

```
@GetMapping("users")
    public String getAllUser(Model model) {

        Flux<User> all = userService.findAll().sort(Comparator.comparingLong(User::getId));

        IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable reactiveDataDrivenMode =
                new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(all, 1,1);
        model.addAttribute("users", reactiveDataDrivenMode);
      
         return "usermainpage";
```

Comment: Do you have the option to return a Mono<String> instead of a String on controller's method saveOrUpdateUser? If you can you can use the then method present on Mono. If you can't, you can use the method block on userDb mono, this will wait execution to finish

Comment: thx. I will try " return   userDb.flatMap(u->{
          return Mono.just("redirect:/admin/users");
      }); "

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know If It works after you test it

Comment: Yes, it works )

Comment: Do you mind if I put my comments as an answer to the question?

Comment: of course! good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the option to change the return type of controller's method saveOrUpdateUser to Mono, you can use mono's flatMap method tô return the redirect String like:

```
return userDb.flatMap((data) -> Mono.just("redirect:/admin/users"));
```

If you can't change the return type, you could use the mono's block method to wait user db execution to finish.